# How to make Spark Worker read data from local mongodb with mongodb-spark-connector?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have got two "mongodb" on two computers. And there is also a "Spark Worker" on each computer. But when I run "spark", it doesn't read data from its local "mongodb". Instead, it reads from one of them. Therefore, only got partial data.
There is a page. https://docs.mongodb.com/spark-connector/master/faq/
.However, after I read it, I  don't understand how to configure at all.

Comment: 1) how are the two `mongodb` connected ? a replica set ? 2) how do you run `spark` to read from these `mongodb` ?